# Parent prop passed as child state not updating on parent prop update

Tags: reactjs, components, renderer, concept

I have recently come across situations where I want my child to re-render whenever the prop from the parent changes given the prop is passed as the initial value of state in Child.

But it is not working as expected.

Is this not the expected behavior?

As the state changes, I am expecting the child to re-render.

Currently, to achieve this I am using an useEffect that setStates every time prop from Parent changes.

Is there a better approach than this? and can mention some points that I am missing to understand this behavior.

To understand the context properly, I have made this [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/parent-value-child-prop-zz4wf8?file=/src/Parent.js).

Expected: Child value should increment when `Increment Parent` is clicked without useEffect.

Comment: You're sidestepping the desired behavior by copying props to state. Don't do that if you don't want that. Just directly use the prop.

Comment: Note: your child DOES re-render. But you copied the prop to local state and then local state is what will be used for every new render. That's by design.

Comment: As @Nikki9696 said you should not initialize state based on props. Here is the article explaining this. https://hackernoon.com/common-pitfall-in-initialising-state-based-on-props-in-react-js-d56795a944aa